# Admin Login Attempts Not Working As Expected in Python Login System

Tags: python, function

I'm relatively new to Python and am working on my first mini-project where I'm tasked with creating a login system for multiple employees and one admin. The requirements are:

Employee data (like id, username, salary, etc.) is stored in a data.txt file.
Employees enter their username and leave the password field empty to log in.
The admin has a predefined username and password, and only 5 incorrect attempts are allowed.
However, when I try to log in as the admin with a wrong password, the system instantly goes through all 5 attempts and displays that the attempt limit is reached. Here's the relevant portion of my code:

```
with open('data.txt') as f:
    data = f.readlines()

user_data = {}  # Renamed from dict to avoid overriding built-in type
for r in data:
    fields = r.split(",")
    id, username, date, gender, salary = fields
    user_data[username] = {"id": id, "name": username, "date of joining": date, "gender": gender, "salary": salary}

def log_in(username, password):
    # ... rest of the login logic ...

username = input("Enter a username: ")
password = input("Enter a password: ")
log_in(username, password)
```

Could someone help identify where I'm going wrong and how to correctly implement the admin login attempt limit?

Comment: In `log_in()` the last else block provides a for loop with only an if / else the values are not being update in that for block therefore the output is not being changed and will continue to print the same output

Answer (score 0):

You have to get again the password in the for loop otherwise the program will go ahead and will do all the iterations. When you use input the program stops until the user insert a new password

```
def log_in(username, password):
    print(dict.keys())
    if username in dict.keys() and password == "":
        print("welcome employee,you will be redirected to employee menu")
        menu_employee()
    elif username not in dict.keys() and password == "":
        print("Incorrect Username ")
    elif username in dict.keys() and password != "":
        print("Incorrect Username")
    else:
        for i in range(5, 0, -1):
            password = input("Enter a password: ")
            if username == "admin" and password == "admin123123":
                print("welcome admin,you will be redirected to admin  menu")
                menu_admin()
            else:
                print("Incorrect Username and/or password, try again")
        if i == 1:
            print("reached attempt limit")
        else:
            print("Incorrect Username and/or password, try again")
```

I also suggest you to remove all white spaces from the input you read for avoid problems

```
with open('data.txt') as f:
    data = f.readlines()
dict = {}
for r in data:
    # Remove all white spaces
    r = re.sub('\s+', '', r)
    fields = r.split(",")
    id = fields[0]
    username = fields[1]
    date = fields[2]
    gender = fields[3]
    salary = fields[4]
    dict[username] = {"id": id, "name": username, "date of joining": date, "gender": gender,
                      "salary": salary}  # use username as primary key since it is what employee use to log in
```

Comment: its working but not optimally, its showing 2 password attempts followed by 2 "Incorrect Username and/or password, try again", not one after the other

Answer (score 0):

Update the value of `password` inside the `for` block

```
    for i in range(5,0,-1):
        if username == "admin" and password == "admin123123":
            print("welcome admin,you will be redirected to admin  menu")
            menu_admin()
        else:
            print("Incorrect Username and/or password, try again")
            password = input("Enter a password: ")
```